# Customize scrollbars using CSS

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I have done this code below to customize my scrollbars but I need to put the arrows in the buttons, how can I made it?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 50px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
display: block;
height: 50px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: refer this: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-styling-scrollbars-to-match-your-ui-design/

Answer (score 0):

You could use background-images positioned appropriately.

See this [**PREVIOUS QUESTION**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765237/using-image-for-webkit-scrollbar-minimum-height-for-webkit-scrollbar-track-pi)

Also [**CSS-Trick article**](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)